# for statement breaks if statement, navbar change color on scroll

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to make navbar which background and li elements changes their colors on scroll

html nav code:

```
<nav  class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                    <img src="img/03.svg" style="width:200px;height:80px;position:relative;top:-20px;">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-main">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right navigation-ul">
                    <li >
                        <a href="#login">
                            aa
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="">
                        <a href="#login">
                            bb
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#features">
                            cc
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#screens">
                            dd
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#payment">
                            ee
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#opinions">
                            ff
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#tutorial">
                            gg
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#why">
                            hh
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#contact">
                            ii
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

Im trying this by perform following JavaScript Code:

```
const navbar = document.querySelector('.navigation'),
      li = document.querySelectorAll('.navigation-ul li a');

window.addEventListener('scroll', function (){
    if (window.pageYOffset > 80){
        navbar.classList.add('navigation-js');
        for(var i=0; i<=li.length;i++){
            li[i].classList.add('li-js')
        }
    }else{
    navbar.classList.remove('navigation-js');
    for(var i=0; i<=li.length;i++){
            li[i].classList.remove('li-js');
    }
     }

 });
```

folowing code gives me 
"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined", 
situation is changes if I use "
li[0,1,2....].classList.add('li-js')" 
and it`s working, but why it doesnt work with for loop?
Im trying for looping also with setAttribute etc.

edit: Javascript code works but put me Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined every time I scroll

Answer (score 1):

Your loop termination conditions are wrong:

```
for(var i=0; i<=li.length;i++){
```

causes one too many iterations. It should be:

```
for(var i=0; i < li.length;i++){
```

If the list has 10 entries, the indexes go from 0 to 9, not 0 to 10.